# Skyrim Companion's quest "Striking the Heart."

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I went where it told me to go in Valheim Towers but there isn't anyone there and I don't know what to do.

Comment: PC, PS3 or XBOX?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently you're not alone: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Striking_the_Heart "bugs": Quote:

> In some cases the waypoint will lead to a random spot adjacent to the designated quest location. This is caused when the player has previously killed the Silverhand leader. Currently only PC users can fix this using console commands.

Looks like restore from previous is your only option unless you're on a pc.