# Can't complete "Striking the Heart" quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am unable to complete "Striking the Heart" quest. I don't suffer from the same [bug](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52954/skyrim-companions-quest-striking-the-heart) where the enemy is already killed. I was able to kill the Silver Hand leader. My quest log tells me to talk to Aela. When I speak to her, I get no options to complete the quest. What are my options? I received this quest a while ago, went off and did other quests, and then came back so loading up an old save isn't much of an option for me. I am playing on Xbox 360.

Answer (score 1):

That quest was bugged for many players since PS3, unfortunately PC users have access to commands to mark the quest as completed. For PS and Xbox this could be a problem.

Maybe [this thread](http://skyrimforums.org/sf/threads/striking-the-heart-i-might-be-screwed.8719/) can help you:

> "Some players have reported that after finishing the two radiant quests for Aela, Blood's Honor won't show up, as Aela won't initiate the quest. This may be caused by a conflict with a radiant quest involving Glenmoril Cavern (Search for the "Iron Mace of Torpor" being an example of this). Attempt to complete the radiant quest as early as possible and it should function as normal."

Answer (score -1):

Well I had that problem with a civil war quest what I did was start from the beginning of the game and when I reached that point everything progressed as normal so that's what I suggest you do try starting over from beginning of the game and that should help you out.

Comment: Starting the game completely over will fix just about any glitch, but is usually an example of a solution that's worse than the problem.

Comment: Maybe but that's what worked for me that's why I suggested it they don't need to follow it I'm just sharing what I did to help someone out.

Comment: Starting over might fix this bug, but is not guaranteed and might also introduce new bugs to fix by starting the game over; the start of endless Skyrim.